# How to void if/else preprocessor macro with another define?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Suppose I have a c header file test.h

```
// test.h
#ifdef A
    int a;
#else
    int b;
#endif
```

Now suppose I want to build my code in such a way that both `a` and `b` are defined if B is defined.
Is there a smarter way rather than:

```
// test.h
#ifndef B
#ifdef A
    int a;
#else
    int b;
#endif
#else
    int a;
    int b;
#endif
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't *define* variables in header files, just *declare* them instead. Also, global variables should be avoided.

Comment: I know about this but I just wanted to keep the example as simple as possible. Consider that a and b can be wathever code. I edited the question

Comment: Please don't edit your question significantly once you have one or more answers, since it can invalidate the existing answer(s).

Comment: Didn't see your answer. Sorry

Comment: No problem - I rolled back your edit.

Comment: While conditional compilation is sometimes necessary, it should be minimized when possible. There are often better ways to do things, but your example is a bit too abstract to offer any better workaround. To me this seems like XY problem.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: what kind of configuration management do you try to achieve with this? Is this just a minuscle side path which justifies such ad-hoc solutions or is the config there a central functionality of your software product?

Comment: Actually, I am implementing unit tests. Now imagine a and b are two structures used for mapping purposes, e.g. GPIO, that are related to different architectures. Thus, the need to exclude a or b depending on the architecture I am building for. Anyway, I would like to build my unit test disregarding the architecture, and this led me to this question.

Comment: @alain, unit tests must use _the same, or most similar_ code to final code, just because if you use different code to test than the production code, you can be hiding in the tests code that is used in production (or it can be used differently, just hiding the failure).  Try to reduce at maximum the differences between code to test against production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just treat the two variables separately and determine the logic for when each should be defined:

```
#if defined(A) || defined(B)
    int a;
#endif
#if !defined(A) || defined(B)
    int b;
#endif
```